# returns an array with null NSCFStrings

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

```
NSArray *pSomerr = [CustomClass.Somedictinary allKeys];
NSLog(@"%@",pSomerr);
```

The above code returns an array full of null strings. The Key's used are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't return an array of nulls.  Without posting more code or more evidence, ti is impossible to say anything further.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help it returned an array with a string that said null. It so happened that i wasnt setting up my key right.Thanks for trying and for your time have a great weekend

Comment: No, really, an **NSArray cannot contain nil**.  So "an array with a string that says null" must mean you put a string in that contained the string "null".  It cannot be a `nil` object.